# Subprocess bad performance in unix shell script

Tags: python, unix, subprocess

I made a server monitoring script that is monitoring mainly network drive usage and cluster's job status. It's really basic and mainly uses unix commands such as top, status, df and such.

I rely using subprocess which works well, but under heavy workload it starts to get really slow and use a lot of cpu capacity. Slowest part is where I grep users from status -a and they have thousands of jobs running.

Script runs over endless while loop.

[image: picture which might give you an idea what I'm doing]

So I'm searching for more effective solutions to do this and any help or hint will be appreciated. I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: Isn't possible to say something about performance of your scripts even don't see them.

Comment: try [`psutil` module](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/) instead of parsing `top`, `df`, etc output. Look at how [`glances`](https://github.com/nicolargo/glances) uses it.

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest you to take a look to [iotop](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/), especially the source code as it is made in python.

The global philosophy behind this is to not use the unix tools (top, df...) but parse their  source of informations that is [/proc](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html).

Opening a file (especially in a memory filesystem like the procfs) is much more faster than forking a process to launch an unix command.